# How does this recursive functional permutation generator work?

Tags: ruby, lambda, functional-programming

This code is written in a functional programming style.
Below is how this should work.

```
(permutations ‘(a b c))  -->  ((a b c) (a c b) (b a c) (b c a) (c a b) (c b a))
```

Please explain how `fold` and `map` work in this code and also recursive permutation...

```
def map(f, lst)
  lst.map{|v| f.call(v)}
end

def fold(f, init, lst)
  lst.reduce(init){|w, a| f.call(w, a)}
end

def permutations(lst)
  lst.empty? ? [[]] : fold(lambda{|w, a| w + a}, [], map(lambda{|v| map(lambda{|p| [v]+p}, permutations(lst-[v]))}, lst))
end
```

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck there? Since this reads like a homework question, you probably have an idea about what most of the code does already.

Comment: Are `fold` and `map` existing methods or are you supposed to implement them?

Comment: Initially I thought you were constructing a method `Array#permutations` that is to mimic the core method `Array#permutation`, but the fact that `permutations` takes an argument that presumably is an array rather than an Integer put that idea to rest. The `fold` method is also a mystery as Ruby has no core method by that name. Please clarify your question.

Comment: ohhhh sorry 'map' and 'fold' are not existing methods. I edited the code. plz have a look at it again. and I'm stuck with interpreting the code.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give this a shot.

```
def map(f, lst)
  lst.map{|v| f.call(v)}
end
```

`map` takes an array `lst` and applies a function `f` on each element of `lst`.

The following example doubles each element of an array.

```
irb(main):007:0> map(lambda {|i| i * 2}, [1,2,3])
=> [2, 4, 6]
```

Next,

```
def fold(f, init, lst)
  lst.reduce(init){|w, a| f.call(w, a)}
end
```

`fold` takes an array `lst`, an initial value `init`, applies function `f` on each element of `lst` and combines it with the previous result to return a value. The result of `f.call(w, a)` is stored in `w`. `w` has an initial value of `init`.

In plain ruby,

```
w = init
lst.each do |a|
  w = f.call(w, a)
end
return w
```

In the following example, `fold` takes the sum of the array by adding each element.

```
irb(main):010:0> fold(lambda {|a, i| a + i}, 0, [1,2,3])
=> 6
```

Now, the main function,

```
def permutations(lst)
  lst.empty? ? [[]] : fold(lambda{|w, a| w + a}, [], map(lambda{|v| map(lambda{|p| [v]+p}, permutations(lst-[v]))}, lst))
end
```

The first part is easy. If `lst` is empty, return `[[]]`.

The second part is

```
fold(lambda{|w, a| w + a}, [], map(lambda{|v| map(lambda{|p| [v]+p}, permutations(lst-[v]))}, lst))
```

We'll work backwards from the innermost.

```
map(lambda{|p| [v]+p}, permutations(lst-[v]))
```

This is simple. For each element returned by `permutations`, we append `[v]` (`v` is defined in the outer map). `permutations` takes the array minus the element `v`.

Here's one example.

```
irb(main):012:0> permutations([1,2,3]-[3])
=> [[1, 2], [2, 1]]
irb(main):013:0> map(lambda{|p| [3]+p}, permutations([1,2,3] - [3]))
=> [[3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Next we go one step higher where we see that the `v` in the inner map is each element from `lst`.

```
map(lambda{|v| map( ... )}, lst)
```

In plain ruby, this is basically

```
lst.map do |v|
  a = permutations(lst - [v])
  a.map {|p| [v] + p}
end
```

Finally, we have

```
fold(lambda{|w, a| w + a}, [], map( ... ))
```

For each element in the array returned by `map`, we add it to `w` which is initially an empty array `[]`.

```
irb(main):019:0> fold(lambda {|w, a| w + a}, [], [[[1, 2]], [[2, 1]]])
=> [[1, 2], [2, 1]]
```

If you want to know why this algorithm works, consider the patterns.

```
irb(main):021:0> permutations([1,2,3])
=> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 2], [2, 1, 3], [2, 3, 1], [3, 1, 2], [3, 2, 1]]
```

which is same as

```
irb(main):023:0> permutations([1,2]).map {|i| i + [3]}
=> [[1, 2, 3], [2, 1, 3]]
irb(main):024:0> permutations([1,3]).map {|i| i + [2]}
=> [[1, 3, 2], [3, 1, 2]]
irb(main):025:0> permutations([2,3]).map {|i| i + [1]}
=> [[2, 3, 1], [3, 2, 1]]
```

Comment: omg thank you so much everything clearly explains how it works..

Comment: um except for one thing.

'irb(main):019:0> fold(lambda {|w, a| w + a}, [], [[[1, 2]], [[2, 1]]])
=> [[1, 2], [2, 1]]'

for this part, how come [[[1, 2]], [[2, 1]]] becomes [[1, 2], [2, 1]] after adding [[[1, 2]], [[2, 1]]] to w?

Comment: @SooIn Each element in [[[1,2]], [[2,1]]] is [[1,2]] and [[2, 1]]. So you are doing [] + [[1,2]] + [[2,1]] = [[1,2], [2,1]]

Answer (score 0):

> Please explain how `fold` and `map` work in this code

Those are simply *message sends* (in other languages they are called *method calls*). They are calling the methods named `fold` and `map`, respectively.

> and also recursive permutation...

The `permutation` method uses the methods named `fold` and `map`. There is no definition for those methods, so this will simply `raise` a `NoMethodError`.

Comment: fold and map are not existing methods. I redefined them.